# This for loop defines a condition but later ignores it

Tags: java, string, for-loop

/*If the for loop goes to i< numbers.length then how would it ever end up at i == numbers.length?  Wouldn't it stop iterating at numbers.length-1?*/

```
class Phone {
    public static void main(String args[]){
      String numbers[][] = {
        {"Tom", "535-5334"},
        {"Bill", "432-5432"}
      };

      int i;

      if(args.length != 1)
        System.out.println("Usage: java Phone <name>");
      else {
        for(i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
          if(numbers[i][0].equals(args[0])){
           System.out.println(numbers [i] [0] + ":" + numbers [i][1]);
           break;
          }
        }
      if(i == numbers.length)
        System.out.println("name not found");
      }
    }
}
```

This example is in my introductory java book and I don't understand it.  It would make sense to me if the for loop used i<=numbers.length

Comment: What exactly is the question? What don't you understand?

Comment: What you've posted doesn't compile. You have a String array but have int elements. And you cannot compare `args[0]` to `1`, they are of different types, `String` vs `int`.

Comment: It cut off my question which is when would the if(i==numbers.length) occur?  It only iterates to i<numbers.length rather than i<=numbers.length.  I also fixed those errors.  Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: It might help you to understand that valid array indexes range from 0 to length-1. So if the loop *were* to execute when `i`==`number.length`, you'd have an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html),

> ```
> for (initialization; termination; increment) {
>  statement(s)
> }
> ```
>
> ...The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop...

So if a name is not found in the `numbers` array, the for loop counter `i` goes up to `numbers.length`, the termination `numbers.length < numbers.length` fails and the for loop exits.

Therefore, `i = numbers.length` at the exit of the loop and the message is printed.

On the other hand, if a name is found within the array, then the for loop `break`s out before `i` reaches `numbers.length` and the message is not printed.